# Limit of an integral over the boundary of a ball

Tags: calculus, integration

Hello I want to compute the following limit
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to0}\left|\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \frac{e^{-|x|}}{4 \pi |x|}dx\right|$$
Where $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, this is a part of a bigger problem so I need the previous limit is equal to $0$ but I am stuck with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the surface of the ball of radius $\varepsilon$, you have $|x|=\varepsilon$ and $dx$ is the area element, so $dx=\varepsilon^2d\Omega$. The integral over the solid angle is $4\pi$. You are left with $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left|\frac{e^{-\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon}\varepsilon^2\right|=0$$